# Why are the limits on 401k much higher than IRA?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira

I'm currently working in a contract position with no option to contribute to a 401k. For 2019, the contribution limit on a 401k is 19,000 vs 6000 on an IRA. Why is there such a big difference? I could understand if you were contributing to both. If you only can contribute to one or the other why can't the limits be more equal?

Comment: People do contribute to both.

Comment: Do you have the ability to a 1099 contract?  If so, you can really sock money away.  A contractor making 40/hr below age 50 can put away about 34K/year.  If they are above 50, add another 6k to that.

Comment: @PeteB.Unfortunately the only option was W2 for this position. If on 1099, what type of account can you put away that much in?

Comment: Wow, so lack of employee benefits and lack of self-employment benefits (20% pass-through deduction, SEP-IRA/solo 401k). Kind of a bummer of a position to be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a 1099 contract worker (self-employed), you should be eligible for a [solo 401(k)](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/one-participant-401k-plans) which potentially has a much higher effective contribution limit because the participant is both the employer and the employee.

*Edited to note:* Since I posted this answer, you have clarified in the comments that you are a W-2 employee. It seems the best option is to seek a job that will allow for 401(k) contributions or allow you to work as a contractor.